# why my pyside custom widget can't show in its parent widget?

Tags: pyside

I want to combine multiple standard pyside widgets into a new widget(my custom widget, named 'RasterWidget') and then show more custom widgets in another widget(named RastersCrlWidget). But strangely, the widgets don't appear in their parent widget when I run the application. I change the custom widget to 'QtGui.QPushButton', then everything is ok. And the custom widget works fine when show separately(don't put it in another widget). I wonder why the standard 'QtGui.QPushButton' can show while my custom widget don't?

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class RasterWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(RasterWidget, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Raster()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


class Ui_Raster(object):
    def setupUi(self, Raster):
        Raster.setObjectName("Raster")
        Raster.resize(250, 212)
        self.lcdNumber = QtGui.QLCDNumber(Raster)
        self.lcdNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 30, 101, 23))
        self.lcdNumber.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
        self.lcdNumber.setObjectName("lcdNumber")
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Raster)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 130, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Raster)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 72, 15))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(Raster)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 72, 15))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Raster)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 70, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(Raster)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 130, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Raster)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Raster)

    def retranslateUi(self, Raster):
        Raster.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Raster", "Raster", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Raster", "reset", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Raster", "read", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Raster", "ID", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Raster", "modify id", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

class RastersCrlWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(RastersCrlWidget, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        raster1 = RasterWidget()
        raster2 = RasterWidget()

**#fine when use standard widget**
#         okButton = QtGui.QPushButton("OK")
#         cancelButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel")

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addWidget(raster1)
        hbox.addWidget(raster2)

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)

        self.setLayout(vbox)    

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('more rasters')  
        self.show()  

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = RastersCrlWidget()
**# appear normally when show separately** 
#     ex = RasterWidget()
#     ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any layout for `RasterWidget`. Without a layout the widget can't calculate its size (`minimumSize`, etc.), so it uses the default and can shrink to `(0, 0)` if needed. Moreover, you add a `stretch` to the main layout, which essentially shrinks your widgets and they are not visible.

In short, use layouts.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. After adding a layout in Raster, everything works fine.